# Comparator for Pair in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, comparator

I can write comparator for specialized types in Kotlin
`class Comparator() : kotlin.Comparator<Pair<Double, Int>>`
But how can I write comparator using generics for all possible types that   extend Comparable<...>?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/natural-order.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create comparator, using helping functions - `compareBy`, `compareByDescending`, `naturalOrder`, `reverseOrder` https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/index.html

For example:

```
val map = mapOf<Int, String>()
// ... add values to the map
val sortedMap: SortedMap<Int, String> = map.toSortedMap(compareByDescending { it })
```

And for your case:

```
val comparator = compareBy<Pair<Double, Int>> { it.first }
```

Custom comparator:

```
class CustomComparator<T: Comparable<T>> : Comparator<T> {
    override fun compare(o1: T, o2: T): Int {
        return o1.compareTo(o2)
    }
}
```

Comment: That's good, but I wanted for some implementation of generic class which can be used, for example, both for Pair<Int, String> and for Pair<Long, Double>

Comment: Why `compareBy` and other helper functions don't work for you? You can use it to create `Comparator` of any Pairs.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following function to combine two comparators into a pair comparator which compares the first value of a pair with the first comparator and then the second value with the second comparator:

```
fun <T, U> pairComparator(
    firstComparator: Comparator<T>, 
    secondComparator: Comparator<U>
): Comparator<Pair<T, U>> = 
         compareBy(firstComparator) { p: Pair<T, U> -> p.first }
          .thenBy(secondComparator) { p: Pair<T, U> -> p.second }
```

Then you use it as following:

```
val source = listOf(1 to 2.3, 1 to 2.0, 0 to 3.0)
val result1 = source.sortedWith(pairComparator(naturalOrder(), naturalOrder()))
println(result1)  // [(0, 3.0), (1, 2.0), (1, 2.3)]

val result2 = source.sortedWith(pairComparator(naturalOrder(), reverseOrder()))
println(result2)  // [(0, 3.0), (1, 2.3), (1, 2.0)]
```

See the full code here: https://pl.kotl.in/BkMOzb8CX