# Kotlin fuction that has 2 parameters for sorting an Map or List

Tags: kotlin

I have a map that contains Keys and Values. i want to transfer it to a List and sort it by value first (integer) and then by Key (String) . This is , it sorts by value but if theres a  tie in the value, i want to "untie" it by sorting it in  Alphabetical order. Is there any kotlin , java function that does this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a possibility to implement a comparator  [Comparator for Pair in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53437312/comparator-for-pair-in-kotlin)

This should work since `yourMap.toList()` is a list of `Pair`s.
The only change that is required is to change the first and second comparator keys as follows (adapted from the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53437312/comparator-for-pair-in-kotlin))

```
fun <T, U> pairComparator(
    firstComparator: Comparator<T>, 
    secondComparator: Comparator<U>
): Comparator<Pair<T, U>> = 
         compareBy(firstComparator) { p: Pair<T, U> -> p.second }
          .thenBy(secondComparator) { p: Pair<T, U> -> p.first }
```

Comment: The first one doesnt work. It simply resorts everything but by String. Ill take a look to the link you sent tho

Comment: Ok. @Kripthonite Sure, you are right. Changed my answer only to a link. Then a custom comparator seems to be a way to go.

Comment: Exactly, what said in your link word. Thank you a lot

Answer (score 3):

The [`compareBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html) function creates a comparator from a sequence of functions returning comparable values. I think something along these lines should work:

```
val myList = myMap.toList()
    .sortedWith(compareBy( { it.second }, { it.first } ))
    .map { it.first }
```

P.S. Not sure what the list should contain in the end. If the pairs are desired instead of just the keys, remove the last line.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun <T, U> pairComparator(
    firstComparator: Comparator<T>,
    secondComparator: Comparator<U>
): Comparator<Pair<T, U>> =
    compareBy(secondComparator) { p: Pair<T, U> -> p.second }
        .thenBy(firstComparator) { p: Pair<T, U> -> p.first }
```

`list = list.sortedWith(pairComparator(naturalOrder(), reverseOrder()))`